# Jsonnet mixin variables and functions

Tags: kubernetes, jsonnet

i am trying to write some wrapper logic for deployments with Tanka/Jsonnet, but seem to be running into some issue, that is probably very simple to solve.

I am trying to create some wrapper-function for a statefulSet that adds e.g. some `stdLabels` at multiple locations, but keep getting an error regarding `Expected token OPERATOR but got "."` on the stateful.new.
It works without the local variable, but i have no clue as to why or how to solve this?

```
{
  local k = import 'github.com/grafana/jsonnet-libs/ksonnet-util/kausal.libsonnet',
  local container = k.core.v1.container,
  local stateful = k.apps.v1.statefulSet,

  fns: {
    customStateful(name, config, c):: {

      local stdLabels = {
        realm: $._config.ingress.realm,
        app: name,
        'app.kubernetes.io/part-of': config.name,
      },
    
      stateful.new(
        name=name,
        replicas=null,
        containers=[]
      )
      + stateful.metadata.withLabels(stdLabels)
      + stateful.spec.template.metadata.withLabels(stdLabels)
    }
  },
  
 $.aed.customStateful('test', cfg, container.new('test', alpine:latest)),

 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `customStateful():: {...}` is returning an *object*, thus every entry there should be `{ key1: value1, key2: value, ...}`, you need to change it to be `customStateful():: (...)` instead.

Pasting below a fixed example:

### main.jsonnet

For other readers, mind you need to run `tk init` to be able to try this code

```jsonnet
// main.jsonnet
//
{
  local k = import 'github.com/grafana/jsonnet-libs/ksonnet-util/kausal.libsonnet',
  local container = k.core.v1.container,
  local stateful = k.apps.v1.statefulSet,

  // plug just to make below code work when referring to $._config, as per provided example
  _config:: { ingress:: { realm:: 'bar' } },

  // cfg used by customStateful 2nd argument in the provided example, create some foo setting
  local cfg = { name: 'foo' },

  fns:: {
    // NB: returning () instead of {}, to be able to return stateful.new() + overloads,
    //     else it would need to be a named field, e.g.  { sts: stateful.new(...) }
    customStateful(name, config, c):: (

      local stdLabels = {
        realm: $._config.ingress.realm,
        app: name,
        'app.kubernetes.io/part-of': config.name,
      };

      stateful.new(
        name=name,
        replicas=null,
        containers=[]
      )
      + stateful.metadata.withLabels(stdLabels)
      + stateful.spec.template.metadata.withLabels(stdLabels)
    ),
  },

  foo: $.fns.customStateful('test', cfg, container.new('test', 'alpine:latest')),
}
```

### output

```shell
$ tk init
$ tk eval main.jsonnet
{
  "foo": {
    "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
    "kind": "StatefulSet",
    "metadata": {
      "labels": {
        "app": "test",
        "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "foo",
        "realm": "bar"
      },
      "name": "test"
    },
    "spec": {
      "replicas": null,
      "selector": {
        "matchLabels": {
          "name": "test"
        }
      },
      "template": {
        "metadata": {
          "labels": {
            "app": "test",
            "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "foo",
            "realm": "bar"
          }
        },
        "spec": {
          "containers": []
        }
      },
      "updateStrategy": {
        "type": "RollingUpdate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you very much! I kinda start hating jsonnet's syntax.. ;) Is there any documentation anywhere about the different brackets and meaning? E.g. difference between putting `local k =..` inside and outside the outermost brackets etc..

Comment: You're welcome @strowi!, Not particularly on that topio, tho I highly recommend https://tanka.dev/tutorial/jsonnet in case you didn't yet follow it. PS: appreciate if you can mark the question as answered, as it'll also help others finding it.

Comment: Okay at least it's not my fault of not searching thorough enough. Still all the differente braces and ":" vs "::" are a little confusing. (And i have my fair share with other languages). ;)

Comment: totally agree!, jsonnet is a language that needs care, patience and practice to "get" it :)